# How to check if any of the gradients in a PyTorch model is nan?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I have a toy model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2, 3)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(3, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = torch.relu(x)        
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

net = Model()

opt = optim.Adam(net.parameters())
```

The training loop is

```
features = torch.rand((3,1))
for i in range(10):
    opt.zero_grad()
    out = net(features)
    loss = torch.mean(torch.square(torch.tensor(5) - torch.sum(out)))
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
```

How can I check if any of the gradients is nan? That is, if just 1 of the gradients is nan print something/break

**pseudocode:**

```
for i in range(10):
    opt.zero_grad()
    out = net(features)
    loss = torch.mean(torch.square(torch.tensor(5) - torch.sum(out)))
    loss.backward()

    if_gradients_nan:
        print("NAN")

    opt.step()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check as below. This approach only checks for the gradients with respect to the model parameters. It does not look at intermediate gradients, actually, those intermediate gradients do not exist after `loss.backward()` is called without `retain_graph=True` argument. For the demonstration purposes, I have multiplied output of first `torch.relu(x)` with `float("inf")` so that some of the gradients become `nan`.

```py
...
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = torch.relu(x) * float("inf")      
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
...

loss = torch.mean(torch.square(torch.tensor(5) - torch.sum(out)))
loss.backward()

for name, param in net.named_parameters():
    print(name, torch.isnan(param.grad))

opt.step()
```

This prints

```
fc1.weight tensor([[False],
        [False]])
fc1.bias tensor([False, False])
fc2.weight tensor([[True, True],
        [True, True],
        [True, True]])
fc2.bias tensor([True, True, True])
fc3.weight tensor([[True, True, True]])
fc3.bias tensor([True])
fc1.weight tensor([[False],
        [False]])
fc1.bias tensor([False, False])
fc2.weight tensor([[True, True],
        [True, True],
        [True, True]])
...
```

To check if any of the gradients is `nan`, you can use

```py
for name, param in net.named_parameters():
    if torch.isnan(param.grad).any():
        print("nan gradient found")
        raise SystemExit
```